# SQL, if row doesn't exist in staging table, and the date is null on the master table, then update date on master table

Tags: sql-server

Having trouble with this. I need to update the row on the master table if the unique item doesn't exist on the staging table AND the date on the master table is NULL.

The problem is my below code updates all the records that have nulls, not just the ones missing from the staging table.

Is there anyway to link these two filters together?
Thanks

```
UPDATE Master_Table
SET Master_Table.Resolve_Date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT
    [Unique_Key]
FROM Staging_Table
WHERE (Master_Table.[Unique Voucher Key] = Staging_Table.[Unique Voucher Key]
AND Master_Table.Resolve_Date = ''
))
```

Comment: techspider noted your NULL problem. Run this to see how NULLs work:

`SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL; SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = ''; SELECT 1 WHERE ISNULL(NULL,'') = ''`

Answer (score 1):

You are not checking `NULL` properly.  There is always difference between `''` and `NULL`'.  `''` denotes an empty string.

Try this code:

```
UPDATE mt SET mt.Resolve_Date = DATEADD(DAY, -1, GETDATE())
FROM Staging_Table st
JOIN Master_Table mt ON mt.[Unique Voucher Key] = st.[Unique Voucher Key]
WHERE mt.Resolve_Date IS NULL
```

Comment: think you need a second close paren after getdate()